# openssl cannot get ENGINE_by_id() to work

Tags: c, openssl

I'm trying to develop my own dynamic engine for Openssl.

To begin with, I would just get to know openssl by loading one of the included engines.

I installed openssl-1.0.1f.

Configured it as such:

```
./config -shared --prefix=/home/user/work/openssl --openssldir=/home/user/work/openssl no-asm -fPIC
```

and doing:

```
make and make install
```

After this I have tested the engine using:

```
./openssl engine -vvvv dynamic -pre SO_PATH:../lib/engines/libgost.so -pre ID:gost -pre LOAD
(dynamic) Dynamic engine loading support
[Success]: SO_PATH:../lib/engines/libgost.so
[Success]: ID:gost
[Success]: LOAD
Loaded: (gost) Reference implementation of GOST engine
 CRYPT_PARAMS: OID of default GOST 28147-89 parameters
      (input flags): STRING
```

That seems ok.

Now I'm trying load the engine in a very simple c-program, but I cannot get ENGINE_by_id to return anything but NULL. I have tried everything I could come up with, but I'm totally stuck.

Below is my code:

```
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/engine.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    ENGINE_load_dynamic();
    ENGINE *eng = ENGINE_by_id("dynamic");

    printf("Error: %s\n", ERR_reason_error_string(ERR_get_error()));

    ENGINE_ctrl_cmd_string(eng, "SO_PATH", "/home/user/work/openssl/lib/engines/libgost.so", 0);
    ENGINE_ctrl_cmd_string(eng, "ID", "gost", 0);
    ENGINE_ctrl_cmd_string(eng, "LOAD", NULL, 0);
    ENGINE_ctrl_cmd_string(eng, "CMD_FOO", "some input data", 0);

    if(NULL == eng) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", ERR_reason_error_string(ERR_get_error()));
        abort(); // failed
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Build as:

```
gcc test.c -o test -I/home/user/work/openssl/include -L/home/user/work/openssl/lib -L/home/user/work/openssl/lib/engines -lcrypto -lssl -lgost
```

Output:

```
./test
Error: (null)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you need to call _e.g._ `OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms()`, `CRYPTO_malloc_init()`, or similar "prepare OpenSSL" functions?  This is what the apps in _e.g._ `openssl-1.0.1f/apps/*` do.

Comment: I was running into this same issue, but calling `ENGINE_load_dynamic` or `ENGINE_load_builtin_engines` resolved it. Your output "Error: (null)" also seems to suggest that `ENGINE_by_id` succeeded?

Answer (score 1):

Because you link the app with local libraries, when running don't forget to export the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or use it inline.

```sh
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/work/openssl/lib:/home/user/work/openssl/lib/engines ./test
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the following and things worked for me

- Create a my_engine.so file and link my_engine.so to the app [Create a basic engine](https://www.openssl.org/blog/blog/2015/10/08/engine-building-lesson-1-a-minimum-useless-engine/)
- Write a try_load_engine function reference(openssl/apps/apps.c)[openssl git](https://github.com/openssl) in the app
- export OPENSSL_ENGINES=path to my_engine.so